# Show Collection Count based on Condition in WPF DataTrigger

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, triggers, datatrigger

I'm having an `ObservableCollection` of type `Employee`

```
public class Employee
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsPresent { get; set; }
    }

ObservableCollection<Employee> EmployeeCollection = new  ObservableCollection<Employee>()
{
    new Employee() { Id=1, Name="John", IsPresent=true },
    new Employee() { Id=1, Name="Peter", IsPresent=false },
    new Employee() { Id=1, Name="Emma", IsPresent=true },
    new Employee() { Id=1, Name="Watson", IsPresent=false },
    new Employee() { Id=1, Name="Sonny", IsPresent=false }
};
```

My XAML Source Code is

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding EmployeeCollection, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="2" MinWidth="160">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    <StackPanel.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsPresent}" Value="False">
                                    <Setter Property="StackPanel.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </StackPanel.Style>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>

    <TextBlock Text="0"/>
</StackPanel>
```

In the XAML `ItemsControl`, I'm showing only the **`IsPresent == true`**. In the Bottom of the `ItemsControl`, there is a `TextBlock`. In that TextBlock, I need to show the Count with Condition **`IsPresent == true`** using Trigger.

Kindly assist me.

Comment: Can you please show us, where the variable Count is in your View Model ?

Comment: @NTinkicht I need the Count of the Item where `IsPresent == true` via dataTrigger. I removed that Binding.